# WPF Ribbon Menu tab permanently visible

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ribbon

I'm programming an application in WPF using the Ribbon menu, part of the requirements for the application is that I need a commands tab, but this tab should be visible at all times and depending on the active document I would enable/disable the appropriate commands.

My question is, does anyone know a way to split the ribbon menu so that the commands tab is always visible on the right side of the menu?

I'm sure there's an easy answer for this, I just haven't found it yet.

Thanks & Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not within the functionality of the ribbon. Why not build a grid with 2 columns, and have the ribbon in the left pane and the custom control on the right? Then you can just style the custom control to match the ribbon.

You can get the source code for the ribbon from CodePlex so you would be able to get the exact style.

It might not be what you wanted to hear, but I think it would be ideal.

Comment: Yes, after a couple of days without an answer, I thought it would come to that, thank you very much for your response.